# Find index of word2vec result in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am building a book recommendation system using word2vec model. Where the outcome is the top 10 recommended books.

Training data

| Book_id | Book_Name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10201 | A Scanner Darkly | some description |
| 10210 | Absalom, Absalom! | some description |

```
from genism.models import Word2Vec
df=pd.read_csv("books.csv")
sentences=[i.split(" ") for i in df['Description']]
model=Word2Vec(sentences,min_count=1,workers=4,epochs=5,window=20)
model.wv.most_similar('scanner',topn=2)
```

Output -

```
[
   ('scanner',0.87455466655556666),
   ('absalom',0.71455466655556666),
]
```

The code predicted the correct keywords. Now I need to extract the course_id for the given keywords from dataframe. so the **output** will be

```
[
     (10201,'A Scanner Darkly','scanner',0.87455466655556666),
     ('10210','Absalom, Absalom!','absalom',0.71455466655556666),   
]
```

I tried using `model.wv.index_to_key` but it's incorrect. I can find index in `Doc2Vec` by using **TaggedDocument** but how can perform the same in `Word2Vec` to get the index of keyword in dataframe.

Comment: AFAICT, you're only training word-vectors based on words in the `Description` field. – not even the `Book_Name` field. So `most_similar()` will only be words that appear in potentially-many different `Description` fields. So there's no robust way to turn a result for the word `'scanner'` into your example output showing just one record-ID, since `'scanner'` may appear in may such records. And to get that list, you'd just scan through (or pre-index) to list *all* records that have `'scanner'` in their `Description`.